# Google drive direct link

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Is there some kind direct links for google drive files, so I could download them by their links? Even temporary links would have been enough.

As I understood, webContentLink can be used only by browsers, downloadUrl can be used for small text files and shoud be used with something like XMLHttpRequest or something else.

Comment: Check out [`this link`](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads?hl=en).

Comment: Please enlighten, how this Q relates to [delphi].

Comment: @TLama, I saw this link. Could you rub my nose where is the answer?

Comment: @user539484, I'm using delphi, that's the reason.

Comment: This is the only way to create direct download link to a file on [Google Drive](http://www.guidepedia.info/2013/07/how-to-get-google-drive-direct-download.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`webContentLink` and `downloadUrl` are the two main links you may use to download a Drive file.

- `downloadUrl` requires you to authorize using OAuth 2.0 (append the access token to the URL using `downloadUrl + "&access_token=" + access_token` or using the Authorization HTTP header). It can be used to download files of **Any** size. Not sure what made you believe it's only for small text files. It's not. The `downloadUrl` is a temporary URL that is valid around 24h.
- `webContentLink` requires the user to be signed in a Google Account. Basically, it uses cookie authorization which is why we usually say it's to be used in a browser. However there is another interesting use-case for that link: If your file is shared publicly  then this link does not require any kind of authorization whereas `downloadUrl` still needs you to use an OAuth 2.0 access token. The `webContentLink` never expires.

Comment: I thought that downloading file with JS is not the fastest way.

Comment: downloadUrl is what I need, because some files cannot be shared publicly, thank you.