# Image direct link from Google Picker

Tags: google-picker

I have Google Picker working well in my project, it imports all data, thumbnails, id etc. of the file. In next step I have to download it, but I don't have direct link. I tried to get direct link with Drive V2 API, but it show 404 error. I have all file data, how could I get the direct link?

Thanks for answer.

EDIT: Drive REST API returns 404 after receiving file ID from Google Picker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service such as : https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/ to get direct file links to google doc files.

However, you can only generate a direct link to a file that you uploaded.   You can not get direct links to files created on your google drive.

Perhaps if you described what work you've done so far we could help you get the rest of the way to your goal.   There are numerous other stackoverflow questions on this topic might contain your answer.

eg:

[Google drive direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168480/google-drive-direct-link)

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/qT02HH5QJRM

https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/

http://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/

Comment: Thanks, I know all of these, but there isn't any solution to my problem... I go through authentication without problem, everything's ok, but when REST API's looking for file with ID from Google Picker it shows 404... So my question is: "How to get direct download link by having data from Google Picker?".